# Convert XML ShimmerFrameLayout into Composable function

Tags: android, xml, android-jetpack-compose

i'm new in android jetpack compose
i would like to  implement **Shimmer effect for Android**. as per given [in this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/)

it's working fine with **xml** approach, but i want to do same with **compose function** (in short embed XML into composable function).

Here is XML Code: shimmer_view.xml

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.ui.recipe_list.UserListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/shimmerFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:shimmer_auto_start="true"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_placeholder_card" />
</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Fragment where i want to use above xml file

```
class UserListFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
//        Traditional Approach Working Fine.

//        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shimmer_view, container, false)
//        return view



//       ComposeView inside fragment

        val composeView = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                Text(text = "Welcome in  Compose-World ")

//                Here i want To use xml file as a Compose View
            }
        }
        return  composeView
    }
}
```

is it possible to inflate or Convert shimmer_view.xml into composable function?

OR

somehow emmbed this xml into compose function.

for reference please share sample code if any. it will help us.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I created this function that help me to inflate an XML layout as a composable instance:

```
@Composable
fun createAndroidViewForXMLLayout(@LayoutRes resId: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val your_xml_Layout = remember(resId, context) {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resId,null)
    }
AndroidView({ your_xml_Layout })
}
```

In your case, you just have to call this function like here:

```
class UserListFragment: Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    val composeView = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            Text(text = "Welcome in  Compose-World ")
            // Here you add the function with the id of your layout **"R.layout.shimmer_view"**
            createAndroidViewForXMLLayout(R.layout.shimmer_view)
        }
    }
    return  composeView
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a composable that gives you the shimmer effect inside another composable:

```
@Composable
fun Shimmer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val shimmer = remember {
        ShimmerFrameLayout(context).apply {
            addView(ComposeView(context).apply {
                setContent(content)
            })
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { shimmer }
    ) { it.startShimmer() }
}
```

And use it as:

```
Shimmer {
    // Your placeholder
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.LightGray))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to the other answers, you don't have to use Facebook's Shimmer library at all and still get the shimmer effect. You can make a reusable shimmer brush with whatever colours you like and use that brush as the background of the item you want to shimmer. Here's an example.

```
@Composable
fun shimmerBrush(): Brush {
    val colors =
        listOf(Grey.copy(alpha = 0.7f), Grey.copy(alpha = 0.2f), Grey.copy(alpha = 0.7f))
    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val translateAnimation = transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0F,
        targetValue = 1000f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        ),
    )
    return Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = colors,
        start = Offset.Zero,
        end = Offset(translateAnimation.value, translateAnimation.value)
    )
}
```

And use it as:

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(shimmerBrush())
```